# Pages refresh or restart or cursor returns randomly, terminal fills with character sequence

Tags: keyboard

I have a hp machine with specs as follows

[image: machine specs]

During start up or normal working, suddenly a page will refresh automatically, the cursor will move to the first line, or if I'm watching a video it rewinds automatically to the start point, even on websites.

When this happens my touchpad is not working and if I open terminal it shows some repeated characters continuously.

```
[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^
[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^
[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~^
```

Screenshot:

[image: terminal full of [[2~^ sequence]

This problem arises with live USB booting too.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your peripherals. What happens if you disconnect your keyboard or mouse ? Does the issue still occur ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is very likely a hardware issue since it appears in live systems too.